# Error: element is not attached to the page document. selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

This is the code:

```py
        prices_parents = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mt-combination.mt-layout-block")
        p_list = []

        for parent in prices_parents:
            prices = parent.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*")
            for price in prices:
                if price.get_attribute("data-column") == "lowestPrice":
                    p_list.append(price.text)
```

I get this error on the line with ".get_attribute":
`Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Since this code in executed ion a loop, I only rarely get the error (like once every 45min), but I need it to work every time.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you somehow moving from that page anywhere?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I do self.driver.refresh() after that code. The page does sometimes change after a refresh, but I am not doing anything else while the code shown is being executed